# How to traverse all packages using python-apt

Tags: apt, python

i want to implement a python code which prints all packages using python-apt in ubuntu. I searched about it, looked at python apt documentation in the link, https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/

However i couldn't find what i want. Do you know how to traverse all packages? If you ask me why i want to do it, it is because that i want to traverse all packages. I can reach the section of a package. If i can traverse all packages, i will group packages by looking the section of packages. As you know, there are more than fifty section for packages as indicated in the link, https://packages.debian.org/stable/

I will look at each package's section, then i put that package into some list . For example if the section of a package is Games, i will put that package into list Games, etc.

How can i traverse and print all packages?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`apt.cache`](https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt.cache.html) and [`apt.package`](https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt.package.html). Adapting the example given for [`apt.package`](https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt.package.html#examples):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import apt
cache = apt.Cache()
Games = [pkg for pkg in cache if pkg.section.endswith("/games")]
print("\n".join(map(lambda x: x.name, Games[1:10])))
```

`cache` is like a dictionary object, with package names (+ an optional architecture label) as the keys. You get use the `cache.keys()` method to obtain all the keys.

Some example output:

```
funnyboat
berusky2
torcs:i386
glaurung:i386
jigzo-data
balazar3-common
val-and-rick
openyahtzee:i386
mupen64plus-ui-console
```